# Are there experiments that are banned from being done at the LHC?

Tags: black-holes, experimental-physics, large-hadron-collider

Are there experiments that are banned from being done at the LHC because they are too dangerous?

Comment: Well, a lot of effort goes into ***not*** testing how long users can be in the experimental halls while the beam is on and live through the experience.

Comment: On a side note, the people who work on/at the LHC would be very definite that they don't do nuclear physics. It's particle physics all the way; and the high energy variety at that.

Comment: See, for instance, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5094/. In general, no man made collider can hope to challenge the natural experiments regularly carried out by ultra-high energy cosmic rays. Statistically, anything bad that could happen at a few TeV has already happened, so nothing bad can happen at a few TeV.

Comment: @dmckee, I would think people doing heavy ion physics at the LHC would say they're doing nuclear physics.

Comment: @MattReece Not at the LHC. They are heavily into gluon plasma etc . But at Isolde, yes http://public.web.cern.ch/public/en/research/ISOLDE-en.html .

Comment: @MattReece It is really about energy range of the physics you study. At high energies nuclear dynamics are simply lost in the noise. Nuclear physics dominates from a few keV up to a few hundred MeV. The transition regime--where it depends on just what physics you are interested in--is hundreds of MeV through perhaps 10 GeV. Above that it is pretty much all particle physics because you just aren't sensitive to the structure or dynamics of the nucleus anymore and instead just see the nucleons and (mostly, or entirely at higher energies) partons.

Comment: @annav and dmckee: what's happening in heavy ion collisions at RHIC and the LHC is certainly not perturbative QCD. And a lot of it is done by people who call themselves "nuclear physicists" and post their papers to nucl-ex and nucl-th on the arxiv. You can deny that it's strictly speaking nuclear physics if you want, but it is a large part of current activity in nuclear physics groups....

Comment: Temperatures are in the ~ 100 MeV ballpark in heavy ion collisions, so it is kind of in an in-between region.

Comment: @MattReece *" a lot of it is done by people who call themselves "nuclear physicists" and post their papers to nucl-ex and nucl-th on the arxiv"* I won't doubt you on this, but all the RHIC guys (only six or ten, to be sure) that I personally know say they are particle physicists. You learn something everyday.

Comment: @JayDillon In your deleted answer where you propose dangers from LHC you are confusing cross section with luminosity (look it up). The two beams collision volume is carefully controlled to be spread out in time and space so that the individual interactions can be measured, otherwise the instruments would be flooded and nothing measurable would come out.So the analogy with high energy cosmic ray collisions holds true.

Answer (score 9):

**Nope**

Concerning mini black holes for example, that would evaporate in the course of a Planck time anyway, you would need a linear accelerator of the size of a galaxy to produce them as Lenny Susskind explains for example.

Any claims that the experiments done at the LHC are dangerous are blatant nonsense spread by people who just wanted to get their minute of fame, media that misunderstood what serious physicists said or dishonestly distorted it in order to better sell their stories etc, ... Nobody should listen to such sensationalist screams of people who have no idea what they are talking about.

Nevertheless, there is an article about the safety of the LHC wherein the (non existing) danger of mini black holes, strangelets, magnetic monopoles, or whatelse you have probably heared about, is scientifically confuted. It is adressed at the concerned public and you can read it [here](http://public.web.cern.ch/public/en/LHC/Safety-en.html). In addition, if any of these phenomena discussed in this report could be discovered at the LHC, this would be a reason for celebrations and dishing out some Nobels, since it would experimentally confirm cool new physics and support theoretical ideas people are thinking about.

Answer (score 7):

I won't discuss issues of mini black holes, strangelets, and so on. I would like to emphasize though that LHC, like any major industrial facility (LHC is not an industrial facility, but it certainly has industrial scale), has some serious safety risks:

dmckee mentioned radiation, but the beam itself is not the only source of risk; the superconducting magnets also present some significant risks, as they also contain a great amount of energy. In principle, this energy can be released during, e.g., a quench event (transition of superconductors to a normal state), producing explosions, damaging helium vessels, and so on.

It is my understanding that safety is a paramount concern at LHC. The following report covering the notorious incident at LHC may be of interest: [Report on 080919 incident at LHC](https://edms.cern.ch/file/973073/1/Report_on_080919_incident_at_LHC__2_.pdf) , in particular, the report says:

> "The technical parameters of the LHC are beyond precedent, and the energy stored in the superconducting magnets huge. Consequently, operation of this machine will always comprise a certain technical risk."

Comment: ...and OHD issues and all the usual rigging risks (bit of the accelerator and the detectors weight tens of tons and have to be moved), and high voltages, and, and, and ... . Yeah, the risks are always there.

Comment: Many things in our modern technical world are dangerous in the manner described in this answer, why should the LHC be worse than other things that can not be completely controlled or guaranteed to run without accident etc ?

Comment: @Dilaton: I am not saying that LHC should not have built and operated, and I agree that our life is impossible without some risks. I wanted to emphasize that providing safety at LHC is a challenging task requiring a lot of effort. Let us hope that there will be no major incidents there.

Comment: @dmckee: do you mean ODH - oxygen deficiency hazards?

Comment: @akhmeteli Yes. Always a stinker when you have superconducting elements...large volumes of cryo-liquids imply the ability to displace a vast volume of air. Especially in the confines of a accelerator tunnel.

Comment: @Dilaton - because a lot of it is run by experimental physicists not engineers! In my experience a lot of senior physicsts need a baby-sitter telling them not to touch that, stand under this or be too near the other!

Comment: @MartinBeckett. *::chortle::* I've worked on collaborations where sitting data collection shifts was a non-negotiable requirement for authorship---even for the theorists. It was critically important for the shift leader (usually a grad student) to know when these guys were coming so that they could look out for them. Mind you, it was worth shooting the breeze with them because they always had a wonderfully different view of the experiment.

Comment: @dmckee - no I mean stopping my head of dept from leaping over a safety gate to where he "thought" a lift platform was. His excuse - the gate wouldn't open. That's because it doesn't open if the lift platform isn't at this level - it stops you stepping off the top of the experiment and falling 20m! The number of senior profs whose first reaction is to bend down to look straight into any sort of beamline/laser/etc cavity is stunning.

Comment: "Please don't look into the laser with your *remaining* eye" :)